# Label assignment for a concave shaped subgrid using a given initially labeled grid

Tags: python, pandas, grid, interpolation

I have a flattened grid saved in two columns of 'x', 'y' in a pandas dataframe as a geographical map coordinates and each row has a numerical label 'z'.
say

`x  |  y  | z
0.1 | 0.2 | 2`

I'm given a new set of coordinates which are a subset of the previous data frame 'x' and 'y' values but not necessarily equal to any given 'x', 'y' value (think of as interpolated coordinates which lie in between of previous 'x' 'y' values but do not equal to any).

Now I want to assign to each 'x' 'y' pairs in the new dataframe a label that honors the labeling in the first more refined data frame coordinates.

Any suggestions?

I cannot use 2d interpolation since my initial grid is flattened and just creating a unifrom 2d grid from the ranges of first grid would not be a good representation of the initial grid since it has many concave regions and holes.